# Sonos Control API: Unable to route the message to a Target Endpoint

Tags: sonos

I keep getting error messages when trying to use the Sonos Control API. Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Example request:

```
POST /control/v1/groups/RINCON_B8E93782FB9401400:363/playback/togglePlayPause HTTP/1.1
Host: api.ws.sonos.com
Content-Type: application/json
Content-Length: 0
Authorization: Bearer <token>
```

Response:

```js
{
    "fault": {
        "faultstring": "Unable to route the message to a Target Endpoint",
        "detail": {
            "errorcode": "messaging.runtime.RouteFailed"
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you might be missing part of the path. The endpoint should be:
/control/**api**/v1/groups/RINCON_B8E93782FB9401400:363/playback/togglePlayPause

If there is API documentation on developer.sonos.com that is incorrect, can you please email the specifics to developer-feedback@sonos.com? Thanks!

Comment: thanks. That worked.

Please review Sonos' developer documentation here: https://developer.sonos.com/build/direct-control/control/

I don't think the "successful play example" includes "api", which it should.